# How do we understand git checkout [dot]

Tags: git, git-checkout

As my understanding, `git checkout` is about moving the `head`.

For example, `git checkout <commit id>` is to move the `head` to the `<commit id>`, `git checkout <branch_name>` is to move the `head` to the `<branch_name>`.

However, `git checkout .` is to discard the unstaged changes. it doesn't seem that there is any business about `head`.

So I can not understand why `git` uses the same key word `checkout` to do two totally no-relative things. Or `git checkout .` still works based on `head`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've noticed, the `checkout` command is overloaded to mean two different things. I think `git help checkout` makes that fairly clear though:

```
git-checkout - Switch branches or restore working tree files
```

There are several forms of the command, the one you're asking about is:

```
git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...
```

In your case the `<tree-ish>` argument is omitted, and the `--` argument to separate options and filenames is ommitted, and `<pathspec>` is `.` (i.e. the current directory). That form of the command is documented as:

> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).

So since you didn't specify a `<tree-ish>` argument, the contents of the files in `.` are replaced with the contents from the index. That means discarding any changes in `.` that have not been added to the index yet.

You can think of it as "checkout these files from the repository", which can either mean from a commit, or from the index (which might contain changes that have been staged but not yet committed).

Comment: Is there a way to recover after executing `git checkout .`?

Comment: @asgs  I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

you can use git checkout to change your branch name & as well as to reset a file (to remote) or to a file in particular branch.

working will depend on the argument after checkout. if its a file name it reset the file as in Current Index.
this is also useful to get the file from other branches.

if it is a branch name it will change the current working branch.